# Plus sign "+" before wchar_t variable

Tags: c++

I have found on the cpp reference website ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/widen)) the following code which I do not understend completely:

```
void try_widen(const std::ctype<wchar_t>& f, char c)
{
    wchar_t w = f.widen(c);
    std::cout << "The single-byte character " << +(unsigned char)c
              << " widens to " << +w << '\n';
}
```

What I do not understand is what does plus sign "+" makes before w variable (`+w`) and before `(unsigned char)c` (`+(unsigned char)c`). Can somebody explain me this?

Comment: I believe it forces a conversion to an integer instead of a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all arithmetic operations, unary plus triggers *integer promotion* of its operand. This results in printing a numerical value of a character. Without it, a different overload of `operator <<` could be chosen. `<< (unsigned char)c` would print a character rather than a number. I believe `std::cout << w` would not compile.

Comment: Yes you are right `std::cout << w` does not compile but `std::wcout << w` does compile.